# How can I track extremly slow objects

Tags: python, opencv

Using OpenCV and python 2.7 I have written a script that detects and marks movement in a stream from a webcam. In order to detect movement in the image I use the RunningAvg function in openCV like so. . .

```
cv.RunningAvg(img, running_avg, 0.500, None)
cv.AbsDiff(img, running_avg, difference)
```

The overall script works great but I'm having a difficult time fine tuning it to pickup subtle motions(breathing for instance). I want to be able to target slow movements breathing specifically. I want to be able to do this without knowing things like color or size of targets ahead of time. I'm wondering if there is another method that is more suited to picking up subtle movements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should probably change the running average parameter way down to like `0.01`
because `0.5` means the running average is half of the last frame.

This is assuming that breathing is the only motion in the frame. If there larger motions or the camera is moving you are going to need a more adaptive baseline.

Comment: what I'm wondering is what the float actually represents. am I throwing out half of the last 12 or 24 frames. or am I throwing out a portion of frames based on time. I can quasi predict the frequency of respiration so if I knew the length of the running avg I could adjust it accordingly

Comment: When a new fram comes in, it is blended into the running average with this proportion. So, a value of 0.2 means that the running average is 0.8 * old_running_average + 0.2 * new_frame

Comment: It's like a half-life. It's the reciprocal of 2x the number of frames it would take the running average to halve it's distance to the current frame if the current frame were not changing.